# MySQL Max() doesn't affect other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database contains multiple values with same `id` but different `build`. What I am trying is to get only the row with highest `build`.

Lets say I have a data like below;

```
|  id  |  build  |  name  |  value  |
|------|---------|--------|---------|
|  1   |  100    | Older  |    5    |
|  1   |  101    | Old    |   10    |
|  1   |  102    | Curr   |   15    |
```

When I run the following query;

```
SELECT id, MAX(build), name, value
FROM myTable
WHERE id = 1 (or id in (1..n) in real life)
GROUP BY id
```

I get the following

```
|  id  |  build  |  name  |  value  |
|------|---------|--------|---------|
|  1   |  102    | Older  |    5    |
```

instead of;

```
|  id  |  build  |  name  |  value  |
|------|---------|--------|---------|
|  1   |  102    |  Curr  |   15    |
```

I am trying to achieve expected result without subquery. Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *without subquery* - why?

Comment: @Stu not allowed to modify the library i am using, and I think whoever wrote this db library, wrote in the time of jesus

Comment: What datatype is build column ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha `smallint`

Answer (score 0):

You must group by `name` and `value` too :

```
SELECT id, MAX(build), name, value
FROM myTable
WHERE id = 1 (or id in (1..n) in real life)
GROUP BY id, name, value
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `LIMIT` query here:

```sql
SELECT id, build, name, value
FROM myTable
ORDER BY build DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

In the event that there could be two or more records tied for the maximum build value, then use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT id, build, name, value
FROM myTable
WHERE build = (SELECT MAX(build) FROM myTable);
```

**Edit:** To handle your problem finding the max build record for each separate `id` groups of records, use either `ROW_NUMBER` or `RANK` on MySQL 8+.  Assuming `ROW_NUMBER`:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY build DESC) rn
    FROM myTable
)

SELECT id, build, name, value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: Each record belongs to unique `build` so I suppose using the one with `LIMIT` option would be faster than the other one?

Comment: If `build` is unique (PK) then first query is best choice. If same `build` value appears multiple times and you want just rows with maximum value of `build` then second query does the job. If you want maximum `build` for given `ID` (or all of them) then this won't do the job.

Comment: @Aarlaneth You are right, first one works for me, but only for single record since it limits 1. I need to get maximum `build` for each `id` in `WHERE IN (x,y,z)`. Second one doesn't work since each ID can have different `build` number

Comment: @Pelin Check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73204849/13535097) I provided, it should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it for you:

```
WITH tempdata as
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id
    ORDER BY build desc) as RowNumber,
    id,
    build,
    name,
    value
    FROM #temptable
)
SELECT id,build,name,value FROM tempdata WHERE RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: MySQL is different from SQL Server...there is no `top` in mysql

Answer (score 0):

Many databases process the "FROM" line first, the "WHERE" line second, and the "SELECT" last. Because of that, you are getting the first column that fits your "WHERE" line. You can eliminate this by adding the max requirement in the "WHERE" line such as:

```
SELECT id, MAX(build), name, value
FROM myTable
WHERE id = 1 (or id in (1..n) in real life) 
     AND build = (SELECT MAX(build) from myTable)
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I tried this before, and unfortunately it doesn't return any result since max `build` value could be different on each row